# Error: Class,interface, or enum error code

Tags: java

I want a GUI that will randomly generate Stars with different colors. Here's the code. It's probably something simple but I can't find the issue lol. I named the class Shapes2JPanel.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Shapes2JPanel extends JPanel {
    // draw general paths
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // call superclass's paintComponent
        Random random = new Random(); // get random number generator

        int[] xPoints = {55, 67, 109, 73, 83, 55, 27, 37, 1, 43};
        int[] yPoints = {0, 36, 36, 54, 96, 72, 96, 54, 36, 36};
        GeneralPath star = new GeneralPath();

        for (int count = 1; count < xPoints.length; count++)
            star.lineTo(xPoints[count], yPoints[count]);
        star.closePath();
        g2d.translate(150, 150);
        for (int count = 1; count <= 20; count++)
            g2d.rotate(math.PI / 10.0);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));
        g2d.fill(star);
    }
}
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing 2D Shapes");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        1Shapes2JPanel shapes2JPanel = new Shapes2JPanel();
        frame.add(shapes2JPanel); // add shapes2JPanel to frame
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE); // set frame background color
        frame.setSize(315, 330); // set frame size
        frame.setVisible(true); // display frame
    } // end main
} // end class Shapes2
```

Comment: `public static void main( String[] args )` is a method and methods must be placed in classes (at least that seems to be the problem based on your indentation). You should also pay attention to number of `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I fixed a lot of compile issues where perhaps a copy and paste went really wrong the only problem was the lack of a moveTo() for the first point on the star.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Shapes2JPanel extends JPanel {

    // draw general paths
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // call superclass's paintComponent
        Random random = new Random(); // get random number generator
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        int[] xPoints = {55, 67, 109, 73, 83, 55, 27, 37, 1, 43};
        int[] yPoints = {0, 36, 36, 54, 96, 72, 96, 54, 36, 36};
        GeneralPath star = new GeneralPath();
        star.moveTo(xPoints[0], yPoints[0]);
        for (int count = 1; count < xPoints.length; count++) {
            star.lineTo(xPoints[count], yPoints[count]);
        }
        star.closePath();
        g2d.translate(150, 150);
        for (int count = 1; count <= 20; count++) {
            g2d.rotate(Math.PI / 10.0);
        }
        g2d.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt(256),
                random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));
        g2d.fill(star);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing 2D Shapes");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Shapes2JPanel shapes2JPanel = new Shapes2JPanel();
        frame.add(shapes2JPanel); // add shapes2JPanel to frame
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE); // set frame background color
        frame.setSize(315, 330); // set frame size
        frame.setVisible(true); // display frame
    } // end main
} // end class Shapes2
```